# Error creating SQL statement

Tags: php, mysql

I made the following code to try and grab the number of entries in 3 tables in a database. The queries work when I use them in `phpMyAdmin` but when I run this code I get:

```
Error creating SQL statement
```

which is generated by the `if(!$stmt)` statement and I have no idea why it's not working. Thanks in advance :)

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';   

$countArtists = $countAlbums = $countTracks = 0;

/* Create queries to get counts from each table */
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artist;";
$sql .= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cd;";
$sql .= "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tracks;";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
if(!$stmt)
{
    echo "Error creating SQL statement";
    return 1;
}

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->bind_result($countArtists, $countAlbums, $countTracks);

echo "<li>Number of Artists: $countArtists</li><br>\n" .
    "<li>Number of Albums: $countAlbums</li><br>\n" .
    "<li>Number of Tracks: $countTracks</li><br>\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want a single query like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM artist) as countArtists, ".
              "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cd) as countAlbums, ".
              "(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tracks) as countTracks";
```

This is one query with three columns, as opposed to three separate queries.

Comment: You missed the comma after the second query, once I added it the query didn't give an error anymore but they all return 0. The only one that should be 0 is tracks because the table is empty.

Comment: Fixed the issue with everything being 0, I forgot to use `$stmt->fetch();`. Thanks for the help :)